# How to update DOM when selector is inside the dynamic code

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id="programming">
    <div id="prosec" class="col-md-12">
        <h2  class="featurette-heading">Text Here...</h2>
        <p class="lead">More Text Here...</p>
        <p class="lead">Guess what... MORE Text!!</p>
        <p><a id="proclick" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#programming">Click for even more text</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following JQuery:

```
$('#proclick').on('click', function(){
    $('#prosec').animate({opacity:'0'},450, function() {
      $('#prosec').empty().append("More Text Yeiii!")}).animate({opacity:'1'},450);
    });
});
```

My problem here is that I am trying to make it so that when I click the proclick anchor again, it runs the same animation again. Right now is only running the first time. Like the DOM did not notice (or JQuery did not sent) the new content. How can I make it so that I can click again on a link that is part of the dynamic code so that it can repeat whatever code I have assigned to it again.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah!. More negative votes for making a question yeiii!! ;) BTw I had already tried about 8 other questions which did not solve my doubt.

Comment: Everytime I come on SO I see a question that requires an delegated `.on`.  Either, they aren't using `.on` correctly, or they are using `.live` or `.click` and trying to accomplish this. No offense, but after the first 100 times of seeing this, it's actually hilarious, because there must be millions of answers for this.  Thousands in just the past month.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Now we see that there are many scenarios that the answers might not work, the OP might not understand (like me) or a mix.

Comment: There is really only a handful of scenarios at most for the delegated `click` event.  They all boil down to the element being created dynamically.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Yes, am getting that now. Thanks friend.

Comment: It's all good, just getting sick of seeing it all of the time I suppose...  Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use event delegation to register handlers for dynamic elements

```
$(document).on('click', '#proclick', function(){
    $('#prosec').animate({opacity:'0'},450, function() {
      $('#prosec').empty().append("More Text Yeiii!")}).animate({opacity:'1'},450);
    });
});
```

if the `programming` element is not dynamic then

```
$('#programming').on('click', '#proclick', function(){
    $('#prosec').animate({opacity:'0'},450, function() {
      $('#prosec').empty().append("More Text Yeiii!")}).animate({opacity:'1'},450);
    });
});
```

Comment: You absolutely rock. Did not occur to me to use document as the selector. You rock! Will accept the answer in 10 minutes ;).

Comment: Why set it to `empty` and than `append` into it?  That is doing more than you need.  Why not just use `.text()` if you are only setting text?  or `.html()` if you are setting both html and text, or even `.content()`!

Comment: @SolomonClosson Many thanks for the suggestion. Don't know why I always thought html or text would be concatenated to the existing text. Did not know about content.

Comment: `.html()` is equivalent to js `innerHTML`, text just sets the `text` Nodes, not affecting the HTML within it.  My apologies, `.content()` does not exist, was thinking of `.contents()` which gets the children of the elements, including text nodes, but you can't set anything with it.